# Flutter await future ignored on button click

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I have the following stateful widget

```
class ItemDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  Item item;
  
  ItemDetailsScreen({required Key key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _ItemDetailsScreenState createState() => _ItemDetailsScreenState();
}

class _ItemDetailsScreenState extends State<ItemDetailsScreen> {

  late UserStore _userStore;
  late Item _item;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _item = widget.item;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _userStore = Provider.of<UserStore>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   //build view of item data and button...
  }

//...
}
```

I want to update the item and display it on a button click.

My button code:

```
onPressed: () async {
            await _userStore.updateItem(item.id!);
            setState(() {
              _item = _item;
            });
          });
```

The updateItem method:

```
@action //mobx annotation
  Future updateItem(String itemId) async {
    _repository.updateItem(itemId).then((isUpdated) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.user!.itemsList.length; i++) {
        if (itemId== this.user!.itemsList[i].id) {
          this.user!.itemsList[i].value = this.user!.itemsList[i].value ! + 1;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

When I trigger the **onPressed** on the button, it always displays the old item value, prior to the update.
The **await** on **updateItem** does not work as I expect: the **setState** method is called before **updateItem** is done executing.
I also tried with `_userStore.updateItem(item.id!).then((value) => {...});` but with no luck.
How can I make this await work?

Comment: `return _repository.updateItem(itemId).then((isUpdated) { ...` - but actually why at all are you using `Future.then` inside `async` method? it only makes things complex

Comment: thank you, it works with the return statement, and works even better after removing the Future.then, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding ***setState*** in ***then*** method?

```
_userStore.updateItem(item.id!).then((value) => setState(() {
          _item = _item;
        }););
```

Comment: yes I tried it, but same behavior as a result